# Puppeteer: How to get parentNode without using evaluate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, acceptance-testing

With Puppeteer, I know how to use evaluate for having some properties like `parentNode` or `previousSibling`:

```
let id = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let wantedHref = $('li a').filter(
        function (index) {
            return $(this).text().includes("Text that I Want");
        })[0];
    //get parentNode
    let id = wantedHref.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    //get  previousSibling
    let expandIcon = wantedLink.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
    expandIcon.click();
    return id;
});
```

I would like to know how I could retrieve these types of properties without using evaluation.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: The underlying CDP has [DOM.describeNode](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-describeNode) command so it should be possible to use it in Puppeteer as well. See the documentation I've linked - the command returns a `Node` response with `parentId` inside which you can query in another `DOM.describeNode` or other commands that accept a node id. To find the original node you can use `DOM.querySelector`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use evaluate?

Comment: @hardkoded I don't want to use evaluate cause it is more difficult to debug and to make pause , and anyway I would like to do this type of operation in several way

Comment: @hardkoded I want to get all div with a specific class  and get all id of their parent

Comment: You could do a mix, use `$$` to get all the elements, and then an evaluate to get the parent of each element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### elementHandle.getProperty('parentNode')

You can use [`elementHandle.getProperty()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) to obtain the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property of the current [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle):

```
const current_element = await page.$('#example');
const parent_node = await current_element.getProperty('parentNode');

await parent_node.click();
```